# Create a new column depending on size of each row in a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, boto3

So, to start with, I have a dataframe containing two columns, `key` and `value` both of type `String`

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 'key1' | 'value1' |
| 'key2' | 'value2' |

and so on and so forth.

The dataframe is created by reading parquet files at a known Amazon S3 location.

`my_df = spark.read.parquet('<some-s3-path>')`

I first tried to iterate over all the rows of the dataframe, to see which rows have > 400 KB (or 400000 bytes) of size using

```
rows = df.collect()
for rw in rows:
  r = ''.join(rw[0:])
  curr_size = sys.getsizeof(r)
  if 400000 < curr_size:
     print(curr_size)
```

Now, what I want to achieve is how do I "filter" out such rows from my dataframe to only have rows having a size of < 400 KB?

I sure can create a `udf` from the above function, but I’m not sure how to use it in the filter or where condition,
meaning all of the following was tried

`my_df.filter(get_size_udf(my_df) < 400000)` or

`my_df.where(get_size_udf(my_df) < 40000)` or

`filtered_df = my_df.withColumn("sizeOf", get_size(small_df))`

But, my lack of knowledge is limiting me in figuring out other solutions. Hence, what are some pointers?

Comment: What is "s3"? Do you mean [Amazon S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3)?

Comment: Thank you @PeterMortensen i edited the question to clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal of filtering out rows from your DataFrame based on their size, you can indeed create a User Defined Function (UDF) and use it with the `filter` function. Here's how you can do it:

1. Define a UDF that calculates the size of a row:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType  # Adjust the return type based on your needs
import sys

def get_row_size(key, value):
    r = ''.join([key, value])
    return sys.getsizeof(r)

get_row_size_udf = udf(get_row_size, IntegerType())
```

2. Use the UDF with the `filter` function to filter out rows with a size greater than 400 Kb:

```py
filtered_df = my_df.filter(get_row_size_udf(my_df['key'], my_df['value']) < 400000)
```

This will create a new DataFrame `filtered_df` containing only the rows where the size of the concatenated 'key' and 'value' columns is less than 400 Kb.

Make sure to adjust the column names in the UDF and the filter function according to your actual DataFrame schema. Also, ensure that the size calculation logic in the UDF matches your requirements accurately.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what you are doing, so you pass in an entire `row` as is, but, now that i look closer dont you think the function is expecting 1 argument, you are passing 2 will blow up unless im reading it all wrong?

Comment: You're correct, and my apologies. The UDF I provided is expecting a single argument (the entire row). If your DataFrame has two columns ('key' and 'value'), you should modify the UDF accordingly.  I have corrected the code, now, the UDF expects two arguments ('key' and 'value') and returns the size as an integer. The UDF and the filter function should work correctly with this adjustment.

Comment: ah! i totally forgot that, there you go done!

Comment: This answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy